# how to apply colorbox on newly added DOM items?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, colorbox

```
$(function () {
    loadFiles('Reports');
    var colorboxOptions = GetColorboxOptions();
    colorboxOptions.onOpen = onViewFileClicked;
    $("a.link_file").colorbox(colorboxOptions);

});
```

I need to populate an empty div with an ajax call `loadFiles('Reports')`.
But how can I add `colorbox` to the newly created `<a>` tags? The code above never works. It appears `colorbox` cannot find all those `a.link_file` tags which are created after `$(document).ready()`. Can someone give me a help? Thank you.

---Update---

`loadFiles` is using jTemplate

```
function loadFiles(folder) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Api/Files/' + folder,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#Container').setTemplateURL("/Templates/FileList.htm", null, { filter_data: false });
        $('#Container').processTemplate(result);
    }
});
```

}

What it does is generating Html code to fill in a `<div>` called `Container`.

Comment: can you show us the code for the `loadFiles()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your loadFiles function is dispatching an ajax call, what's probably happening is it's spawning a new thread to deal with grabbing the data and continuing with the rest of the function. When you want something to happen after an ajax call completed, you need to put what you want to happen in the "success:" function in the ajax call. Otherwise, you can't guarantee that things will happen in the order you want.

If you can edit the loadFiles function, just put

```
var colorboxOptions = GetColorboxOptions();
colorboxOptions.onOpen = onViewFileClicked;
$("a.link_file").colorbox(colorboxOptions);
```

in the success function of the ajax call.

Alternatively, you could add

```
async: false,
```

to your Ajax call. I personally don't recommend this route though as it can lead to other errors, but if you're using this function for multiple things, this might be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    loadFiles('Reports');
});

function loadFiles(folder) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Api/Files/' + folder,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#Container').setTemplateURL("/Templates/FileList.htm", null, { filter_data: false });
        $('#Container').processTemplate(result);

        var colorboxOptions = GetColorboxOptions();
        colorboxOptions.onOpen = onViewFileClicked;
        $("a.link_file").colorbox(colorboxOptions);
    }
});
```

I make no promise, but I'm guessing that your colorBox code needs to run after the ajax call returns, try placing it in the success call back as above.

Comment: Thank you, gingerbreadboy. You also provide the correct answer.